# Check if user is close to scrolling to bottom of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My website has a Bootstrap modal. My end goal is to add infinite scrolling to the modal so that when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the modal, it loads more data from the server and appends the data to the modal.

Here is my code so far. All I have right now is a scroll event on the modal:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33247/

Note: The height of the modal on my website can vary. Sometimes it can be just 1 paragraph of text.

My question is, how can I check if the user is close to scrolling to the bottom of the modal?

In more technical terms, how can I check if the bottom of the window is at the same position as the bottom of the modal?

---

### Update

I found that this solution works, however, it seems a bit complicated/long. Any way to shorten it?

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33271/

---

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#exampleModalLong").on("scroll", function() {
    console.log("scroll");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m no expert in JavaScript and personally I have to go back to the docs every time I need to remember the difference between document, window and viewport when I have to deal with scroll events but I think this will get you on track.

Note: this will work with the entire document´s scroll event, try and apply it to your modal's body tag and let me know:

```
//in this test case your limit is going to be 20
$(document).scroll(function (){
    if($(this).height() - $(this).scrollTop() - $(window).height() < 20){
        console.log('time to show new content');
    }
});
```

hope it helps

**EDIT**

```
$('.modal-content').scroll(function (){
    if($(this).height() - $(this).scrollTop() - $('.modal-dialog').height() < 20){
        console.log('time to show new content');
    }
});
```

If what u r going for is just for `.modal-content` to scroll inside `.modal-dialog` and everytime `.modal-content`'s *content* is about to run out, append more, then I think this is what you need.

Now if you want the ***entire*** (and I really have to emphasize) modal to scroll while the background stands still, please let me know how u were able to achieve it without encapsulating it in anything else.

good luck and let me know

ps: if this works, you should really take a look at [Erik Philips'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209259/erik-philips) answer.

Comment: Can't seem to get the results I'm looking for, even when applying the modal's body.

Comment: Were you able to using my JSFiddle?

Comment: ok, the code i posted i tried with a minimalist html doc, and it works there, that is why i told u to test it in your modal. u should try and see what it *is* doing and share it with us for further help, ill check ur fiddle now

Comment: i saw the fiddle, now i think i didn't understand something, what u r scrolling *is* the entire document, i thought what you wanted to scroll was the body inside the demo, am i right?

Comment: I found the following works, but it seems a little long/messy: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33269/ Any idea if this can be optimized/shortened?

Comment: please, explain something: are the entire document and the *entire* modal scrolling at the same time, see i thought you wanted to scroll only the content of the modal's body, but your fiddle told me otherwise,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I simply want to check if the bottom of the window is at the same position/height as the bottom of the `.modal-content`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more of a throttled version of [J.M. Echevarría's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44356600/209259) (assuming the scrolling code is correct).  Sometimes issues arise that you can overwhelm the browser with events (either loading more content then desired and/or slowing down the browser which can give a user a negative experience of the website).

```
$(document).scroll(function (){
  var timerId;
  if($(this).height() - $(this).scrollTop() - $(window).height() < 20){
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('time to show new content');
      }, 250);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#exampleModalLong').on("scroll", function() {
    if(($('#exampleModalLong').hasClass('in') && !$('body').hasClass('scrl'))&&($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('.modal-footer > button').offset().top)){
      $('body').addClass('scrl');
      setTimeout(function(){
        alert('foo');
        $('body').removeClass('scrl');
      }, 900);
    }

  });
});
```

[See](http://jsbin.com/qeyede/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight for checking with current scroll position

Example:

```
$("#exampleModalLong").on("scroll", function() {
var isEnd = this.scrollHeight - this.scrollTop === this.clientHeight;
if (isEnd) {
   alert('Bingo');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if you have reached the bottom of the bootstrap modal, you can use the below code snippet :

```
$('.modal').scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        alert('You have reached the bottom of the modal')
    } 
});
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: The checks if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, not the bottom of the modal.

Comment: The code checks whether the user has scrolled to the bottom of the modal, if the modal overlay is having scrollable content area present. .i.e. if the height of the modal is overflowing beyond the height of the page. In this case the bottom of the modal will be the bottom of the page.

Comment: You can modifyt the condition in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33269/) mentioned by you to:
  var position = ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() - this.scrollHeight);